# Check only used space on CentOS server

Tags: linux, awk

I want to view only column named Use% i have tried to do like this:
`df -h | awk '{print $%}'`

But i have too long names in Filesystem colum and when i do that it show me mixed colum Use% and Mounted on.

How can I display only the Use% column

Comment: Can you show your output of `df -h`? and add it to the question. Does the file-system have spaces in the name?

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: It _won't work_, Please re-read the question,  `have too long names in Filesystem colum`, so you can't use it directly on column 5 for the rows next to header, need to dynamically identify the column containing a `%` at end, look at my answer.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: You don't understand what I am trying to say. Assume my file-system name is for e.g.  `my System 1`,  run your command on that and see what happens. It won't work, because your name alone has parts with few whitespaces, and `$5` won't probably match with the name under `Use%`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR: If you still want to do that way, nothing stops you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal case, if the *file-system* column does NOT have whitespaces to worry about, e.g. for an output as

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:/msys64       238G  132G  107G  56% /
```

doing `df -h | awk 'NR>1{print $5}'` would have been just fine to print the `5th` column representing the usage. But for a case as complex as you said, when the file-system name is expected to have some spaces, looping through the columns to find the column matching `%` would be the right approach,

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (match($i,/\%$/)) { print $i; break } }'
56%
```